# Translate FFT data to match ComputeSpectrum FFT output

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio, fft

I'm used to using `SoundMixer.computeSpectrum`, but I need to get some data on-the-fly from the microphone (and I can't use the SoundMixer with the microphone).

I'm having trouble translating the FFT data (from [this class](http://gerrybeauregard.wordpress.com/2010/08/03/an-even-faster-as3-fft/)) as shown in [this excellent spectral analysis example](http://gerrybeauregard.wordpress.com/2010/08/06/real-time-spectrum-analysis/) to match the `ByteArray` output from `computeSpectrum`. My existing code is built to handle the data received from `computeSpectrum` (with `FFT` set to `true`).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to generate a dynamic wave form for the audio coming in from the microphone or...?

Comment: No. I want to analyze the audio, just like in the example link, but I need to perform additional analysis.

Answer (score 2):

In the sample code you have linked, the `m_mag` vector contains the spectrum data itself. If you want to modify it to work with existing code that is designed to work with `computeSpectrum`, you should write the values in this vector to a `ByteArray` like so:

```
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

var fftBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
for(var i:uint = 0; i < N/2; i++)
{
    var re:Number = m_tempRe[i];
    var im:Number = m_tempIm[i];
    var mag:Number = re*re + im*im;
    // Old method: write to vector
    // m_mag[i] = Math.sqrt(sample);
    // New method: write to ByteArray
    fftBytes.writeFloat(mag);
}
// microphone is mono, so make a copy to match computeSpectrum's stereo output
fftBytes.writeBytes(fftBytes, 0, fftBytes.length);
```

Your existing code can then look at `fftBytes` directly instead of calling `computeSpectrum`. Note that we copy the values a second time at the end of the `ByteArray`, to simulate the fact that `computeSpectrum` always returns stereo data, but the microphone is mono. You could also gain a little bit of speed by adjusting your existing code to accept mono data and to look at the `m_mag` vector, instead of writing it all to a `ByteArray`.

Additionally, you may want to change the `SAMPLE_RATE` and `N` constants at the top of the code to `44100` and `9` respectively. This will match the default `computeSpectrum` behavior of returning 256 values per channel, sampled at 44100Hz.

Comment: Very helpful, Mike. I'm currently using ASFFT (an Alchemy-based solution) to try to complete the project, but I hope to come back around to a pure AS solution once everything is in place. Thanks so much for you input!